# Difficult implementing ping/latency functionality on unpreviliged host machine with Python

Tags: python, django, linux, pythonanywhere

I made a webapp (python/django) which pings different servers and returns ping values.
here's the [Link](http://invoron.pythonanywhere.com/).

It has a pingserver(ip,sev) function that uses the os/system fping(can be used with /bin/ping) to get output and strips to get the value.

```
def pingserver(ip,sev):
    ping_response = subprocess.Popen(["/usr/bin/fping","-c1","-t400",ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
    latency = str(ping_response)
    ping_value=latency.split('ms')[0].split(',')[-1]
    if len(ping_value) <= 3:
        return(sev,'unknown')
    else:
        return(sev,ping_value)
```

it works fine in my localserver but the code doesn't work in the hosted machine because '/bin/fping' doesn't exit.
I cannot do following:

1. install fping or ping (i dont have root permissions on server)
2. can't use pyping (needs root for raw socket creation )
3. can't use ping/fping executables ( needs root permission )
4. can't use http.connnection.request or similar ( i need exact ping value ; not imformation about server up or down )

So my question is how can I get ping/latency under these circumstances so that my code functions.
(any suggestions related rewite of code or usuage of library are appreciated)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like ping has potential security problems associated with it, so PythonAnywhere wouldn't allow you to run it. But you can popen something like

```
time nc -zw400 <host> <port>
```

(using a bash shell for the `time` command) to get latency stats